# Azure Kusto Query to trim the name of a full Azure Resource ID

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, azure-log-analytics

I have a query that is taken from diagnostic logs output from Azure App Services and pushed into a Log Analytics Workspace.

```
AppServiceAppLogs
| where TimeGenerated >= now(-1h) and Level == "Error"
| project TimeGenerated , _ResourceId , Source, ResultDescription
| summarize ErrorsLogged = count() by _ResourceId
| order by ErrorsLogged
| render piechart
```

When the chart (any chart) renders it displays the correct full `_ResourceId` table contents, such as...

```
/subscriptions/00000-000000-000000-00000000/resourcegroups/my-resource-group/providers/microsoft.web/sites/my-webapp
```

These end up being too long to display. Is there anyway to trim out the `/subscriptions/00000-000000-000000-00000000/resourcegroups/my-resource-group/providers/microsoft.web/sites/` in the results?

Thanks in advance

Comment: May be `split` is better? Something like `split(_ResourceId, "/", 7)`, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/splitfunction

Comment: if not, there is `substring`, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/substringfunction

Comment: @IvanIgnatiev, you have good ideas, it's better to post them as answers, and not as comments :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
AppServiceAppLogs
| where TimeGenerated >= now(-1h) and Level == "Error"
| project TimeGenerated, ResourceName=tostring(split(_ResourceId, "/")[-1]), Source, ResultDescription
| summarize ErrorsLogged = count() by ResourceName
| order by ErrorsLogged
| render piechart
```

Basically it splits the `_ResourceId` using `"/"` as delimiter (which gives you an array) and then gets the last element in that array and aliases it as `ResourceName`.

References:

- **split()**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/splitfunction
- Retrieving the 'index'-th value from the end of the array is done by `arr[-index]` (accessing the last value is done using `arr[-1]` - here's the [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/dynamic#dynamic-object-accessors).

Comment: I've edited the answer to a more efficient version: accessing the last element of an array can simply be done by accessing with index==-1, like this: `MyArray[-1]`.
In any case, an even more efficient version is: `split(_ResourceId, "/", 8)[0]`.

Comment: @SlavikN - Thanks. I was not aware of this. Can you share a link about the -1 index so that I can read more about it.

Comment: @SlavikN thanks! The first 3 lines work, however the count() by _ResourceId doesn't work - "'summarize' operator: Failed to resolve scalar expression named '_ResourceId'". I tried the count by ResourceName but get "Summarize group key 'ResourceName' is of a 'dynamic' type. Please use an explicit cast (for example, 'summarize ... by tostring(ResourceName)') as grouping by a 'dynamic' type is not supported." - Thanks

Comment: @nmca70 - I have updated the answer. Let me know if it works for you now.

Comment: I've edited the answer to add a reference on retrieving the 'index'-th value from the end of the array: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/dynamic#dynamic-object-accessors

Comment: @SlavikN - Thank you so much! It is very much appreciated.